# Добавление пользователя в чат telegram с помощью бота в Rails

Tags: ruby, telegram, telegram-bot

Подскажите пожалуйста, возможно ли научить бота добавлять пользователя в групповой чат при помощи Ruby (планируется завернуть это в приложение на Ruby on Rails)?

Comment: Rails тут слегка ни при чём. Rails что скажут делать на Ruby при запросах, то и сделает. Вопрос состоит скорее в том, можно ли это сделать на Ruby. А как это **хоть на чём-нибудь** делается, вы выясняли?

Comment: пока не могут понять, возможно ли это в принципе, поэтому и спрашиваю "возможно ли научить бота добавлять пользователя в групповой чат "

Comment: Ruby тут не причем, bot может все, что есть в документации к нему. Такой функции я там не видел.
[Telegram Bot API][1] [1]:https://core.telegram.org/bots/api

Answer (score 1):

Боты, основанные на официальном Bot API такого не умеют — нет подходящего метода в API.

Вообще говоря, основная идеология ботов для телеграм: пользователь взаимодействует с ботом, но не наоборот. Боты не могут самостоятельно начинать диалог с пользователем, приглашать его во всякие группы, удалять сообщения и пр.

Разумеется, все эти ограничения можно обойти, используя для этого протокол MtProto и его реализацию [telegram-cli](https://valtman.name/telegram-cli).